# Redirecting with https www and trailing slash with vhosts, apache2 and htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, ubuntu, redirect, apache2

I have a strange issue with redirecting URLs in an edge case scenario. All of my applications using my framework use https with forced www and a trailing slash on the URLs. The https and forced www redirects are done with virtual hosts (i've included the normal apache2 conf and the certbot https generated ones). The redirection all works apart from a very edge case scenario when one letter is put at the end of the URL with no trailing slash where index.php gets added to the URL, for example:

example.com/aa redirects to example.com/aa/ correctly
example.com/a redirects to example.com/index.php/a/ incorrectly

I can't seem to nail down what is causing this issue, but i'm sure its to do with the htaccess file as the 301 redirect (as seen in chrome network) happens before the request hits the code of the website. This happens on both my local and live environments.

Many thanks for all advice!

I've tried using different htaccess configurations with no luck (just made the situation worse).

example.com.conf:

```
# domain: example.com
# public: /var/www/example/public/

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ServerName  www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/example/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example/log/access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

example.com-le-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@examplw.com
  ServerName  www.example.com
  ServerAlias example.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /var/www/example/log/error.log
  CustomLog /var/www/example/log/access.log combined
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^.]+$
    RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Expecting:

example.com/aa to redirect to example.com/aa/
example.com/a to redirect to example.com/a/

Images & files should redirect without the trailing slash.

Requests that already have the trailing slash should not redirect at all.

Comment: `^(.+[^/])$` – this demands one or more characters that match `.`, followed by one non-slash character - so at least _two_ characters. So this does not match a single `a`. (And that preceding RewriteCond seems rather pointless?)

Comment: Ditch the RewriteCond, and try `RewriteRule !/$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]` instead. Pattern negation by prefixing a `!` works in RewriteRules as well, and since you are using %{REQUEST_URI} in the replacement part anyway, you don’t need a _positive_ pattern that would capture anything to begin with.

Comment: @misorude Thank you for your reply, unfortunatel ditching the `RewriteCond` and replacing the `RewriteRule` with your suggesstion seems to cause a _Re-directed too many times_ error, it adds an exatra slash to the homepage and other pages seem to have many slashes appended to the end for example `example.com/about-us///////////////////`. The rule also seems to add the strailing slash to my assets requests which breaks them as not found. Do you have any other suggestions to this?

Comment: Ah, shoot, ma bad - now I forgot myself what I always preach, when rewriting is configured in .htaccess, the local URI path never starts with a slash, because that has been stripped of at this point already. “Not empty or trailing slash” could work, so try `!^$|/$` perhaps.